# Uncaught ReferenceError: showNotification is not defined when submitting my form

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, toast

I'm in the middle of creating a form (dev) where you can enter a Cardknox Transaction API and it will give me a response back whether it went thru or not, , i'm trying to add toast notificatiom, so that when I hit submit it should pop up a notification that it was approved, or error message, etc. however, when I'm trying to hit submit it gives me the below error messages in the console[toastify error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do2SG.png)

see my code below

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "server")));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views"));

app.get("/gatewayjson", (req, res) => {
  const xKey = req.query.xKey;
  const xCommand = req.query.xCommand;
  const xCardNum = req.query.xCardNum;
  const xExp = req.query.xExp;
  const xAmount = req.query.xAmount;
  const xSoftwareName = "Cardknox";
  const xSoftwareVersion = "2.1";
  const xVersion = "5.0.0";

  const body = JSON.stringify({
    xKey: xKey,
    xCommand: xCommand,
    xCardNum: xCardNum,
    xExp: xExp,
    xSoftwareName: xSoftwareName,
    xSoftwareVersion: xSoftwareVersion,
    xVersion: xVersion,
    xAmount: xAmount,
  });

  request(
    {
      url: "https://x1.cardknox.com/gatewayjson",
      method: "POST",
      body: body,
    },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(body);

        const responseObject = JSON.parse(body);
        const xRef = responseObject.xRef;

        res.render("template", { xRef: xRef });
      }
    }
  );
});

app.listen(3060, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port 3060");
});
```

template.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/head') %> 
  <body>
    <script src="toastify.js"></script>
    <form
      action="/gatewayjson"
      method="get"
      onsubmit="showNotification('<%= xRef %>')"
    >
      <label for="xKey">Cardknox Key:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="xKey" name="xKey" /><br />
      <label for="xCommand">Command:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="xCommand" name="xCommand" /><br />
      <label for="xCardNum">Card Number:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="xCardNum" name="xCardNum" /><br />
      <label for="xExp">Expiration Date:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="xExp" name="xExp" /><br />
      <label for="xAmount">Amount:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="xAmount" name="xAmount" /><br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

toastify.js

```
function checkRequiredFields() {
  const requiredFields = document.querySelectorAll("[required]");

  for (let i = 0; i < requiredFields.length; i++) {
    if (!requiredFields[i].value) {
      Toastify({
        text: "Please fill in all the required fields",
        duration: 10000,
        close: true,
        gravity: "top",
        position: "left",
        backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)",
        stopOnFocus: true,
      }).showToast();
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function showNotification(xRef) {
  if (xRef === "") {
    Toastify({
      text: "Error: xRef is missing",
      duration: 10000,
      close: true,
      gravity: "top", // `top` or `bottom`
      position: "left", // `left`, `center` or `right`
      backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)",
      stopOnFocus: true, // Prevents dismissing of toast on hover
    }).showToast();
  } else {
    Toastify({
      text: "Transaction Approved with xRef: " + xRef,
      duration: 10000,
      close: true,
      gravity: "top",
      position: "left",
      backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)",
      stopOnFocus: true,
    }).showToast();
  }
}
```

please let me know what's wrong here,  thanks

Comment: java is not javascript.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @jospehmonn your question was tagged `java`, but [java is not the same as javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: where do you see java,  I tagged it javascript, node.js, ejs, toast,
i'm not sure where you see it

Comment: @jospehmonn no, you tagged it as java, [I edited the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74995833/revisions) and changed it.

Comment: ah, now i see it

Comment: I ended up adding my custom message, and it worked